# Plot3D seems to be ignoring points

Tags: plotting, distributions

Consider the following function:

```
f[n_, i_, g_]:= PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, g], i]
```

The output of

```
Plot3D[f[100, i, g], {i, 0, 100}, {g, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

produces:

[image: 3dplot]

By only looking at the 3D plot would incorrectly suggest that, say, f(100, 25, 0.2) = 0. However, the value of f at this point is approximately 0.04. My question is: how can I make the output of Plot3D more accurate for the function above?

Comment: What is `DF[]`? Also, `N[]` is a reserved symbol; don't use it as a variable.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be PDF, not DF.

Comment: How odd. Try this: `With[{n = 100}, Plot3D[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, g], i] // Evaluate, {i, 0, 100}, {g, 1/10, 9/10}, PlotRange -> All]]`.

Comment: Thanks! Using `Evaluate` solves the problem. I wonder why I need to use Evaluate though.

Comment: Recommend that you add the option `MaxRecursion -> 5` to the plot.

Comment: Compare `f[100, 25.01, 0.2]` and `f[100, 25.0, 0.2]`. -- Try something like `Plot3D[f[100, Floor@i, g], {i, 0, 100}, {g, 0.1, 0.9},  Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 4]` or use `Round[i]` or `Ceiling[i]` instead of `Floor[i]` as desired.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Cool. As you suggest, the problem has to do with the fact that this is a discrete distribution and, consequently, that `i` is a discrete variable.

Comment: However, when `n=10` the graph obtained using `Evaluate` is different from the graph obtained using `Floor`. That is, the graphs produced by `Plot3D[Evaluate@f[10, i, g], {i, 0, 10}, {g, 0.1, 0.9}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 4]` and `Plot3D[f[10, Floor@i, g], {i, 0, 10}, {g, 0.1, 0.9}, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 4]` are not quite the same.